# Having a problem with Next and Previous Links

Tags: archives

I've run into an issue with next/previous (which I implemented on archive / author pages successfully by just following the codex instructions).

I have created a custom category page for "Pine Trees" I display the newest "Pine Tree" post and then another 11 "Pine Tree" posts. But this custom page hijacks the whole "Pine Tree" archive, and there doesn't seem to be any way around it with post title or anything.

Has anyone run into something similar?

Thanks

Comment: You are most probably using the same slug for your page as the slug for the archive. You cannot have a page and an archive with the same slug, you need to change either of the two slugs to be unique

Comment: I tried using different slugs, changing the slug / title / both to "pinetree-news" and "Pine Tree News" but it didn't change the hijacking. Even when I don't change it, it is still a page found at "site.com/pinetrees" while the actual category is "site.com/categories/childcategory/pintrees."